# How to run a sensitivity analysis to find out significant interaction terms in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a longitudinal dataset and I ran several linear mixed effect models.
I got main effect model

```
lme1 <- lme(Y~A+B+C+D+Time, random = TIME | ID, data)
```

How do I find out significant interaction terms of predictors * Time?

Do I manually plug in each `predictor*Time` like

```
lme2 <- lme(Y~A+B+C+D+Time+A* Time+B* Time+C* Time+D* Time, random = TIME|ID, data)
```

Or is there a better way to find significant interaction terms in linear mixed effect model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but there is a faster way:

```
lme((Y~A+B+C+D+Time)^2, random = TIME | ID, data)
```

The R formula syntax using ^2 means "all two-way interactions of the variables inside enclosing parentheses".

```
lme((Y~A+B+C+D+Time)*Time, random = TIME | ID, data)
```

When you only want interactions with time